# Nullpointer exception in Soundcloud HTML5 Widget API when creating dynamically new player iFrames

Tags: html, gwt, html5-video, soundcloud

I could reduce my problem on a small code snippet. The code creates dynamically an SC player iFrame and displays the ready status. If there is already an iFrame, it removes the old one and creates a new one (runable [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7cdbM/72/) on JSFIDDLE):

```
var player;
var playerId;
var iframe;
var printReady=
function(data)
{
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Ready";  
};
function createSoundCloudIframe()
{
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Player not ready";
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");

    // Remove last Iframe
    if(iframe != null){
        player.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.READY);
        contentDiv.removeChild(iframe);
    }
    // Create a new Iframe
    iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.id = playerId + "ScId";            
    iframe.src = "http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F41867062&show_artwork=true";

    // Append Iframe
    contentDiv.appendChild(iframe);

    // Show ready status
    player = SC.Widget(playerId + "ScId");
    player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, printReady);

    playerId ++;
};
```

The code runs fine when it is executed the first time. But when you try it a second time a nullpointer exception (developer console) will be thrown in this method of api.js:

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentWindow' of null
function s(a) {
            return a.contentWindow || a.contentDocument.parentWindow
}
```

The method which causes the exeption is `SC.Widget(iFrameId);`

This problem is in my case not solvable with `SC.Widget(iFrameId).load(url, options);` function and a hiding of the iFrame:
I wrote a google-web-toolkit wrapper for the SC widget api and use this wrapper with other gwt mediaplayer wrappers in a much bigger project. In this project the exception is thrown repeatedly with a delay of milliseconds which slows down everything. The codesnippet above is only a pure javascript reduction of the problem.

I really need a workaround which removes and clean up all dead references in the api.js when the iFrame is removed! I'm looking for such a workaround for month.

Comment: You could try just using a different, not iframe based player?

Comment: Please clean up the question. Keep it simple. One question at a time. I am inferring the issue appears in gwt with jsni as well as pure javascript!!! Retagging question with HTML5 to have more traction!!

Comment: @Liam Bigelow. I've also wrote a wrapper for the soundcloud flash player. But this player is deprecated and I've got much more problems with event listening in IE.